# Running test using Terratest but it throws "no test files" error

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terratest

I am working on terratest for terraform in Azure. Currently making use of an example code as given in the following link- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/best-practices-end-to-end-testing.

When I try to run `go test -v` it gives out [no test files], not sure why.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that when you are `go test` to be inside the `test` directory. `cd` into test directory and than run the command

Comment: I have changed the directory to the directory where .go files are present..still i am getting the same error